# Can we show a loading status like in android asyncTask until we get the response while using an HTTP Post request in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am quite new to swift programming. I learned that NSURLSession uses Asynchronous communication to get response from the url. How could i possibly show an loading status till the request is complete and i get the response. for example, If i have a value submitted to NSurlsession from a textfield and I have to display another textfield containing response from the httprequest. I should display a laoding status when i click the submit button till i get the response , so that user know some process is going on like "Loading, please wait!!".

Also how do we use handlers to know that we got the response. Likewise i would hence not be returned nil values

This is my function right now

{

class func postURL(var postString:String,var postLink:String) -> NSDictionary

```
{

    let link = postLink

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:link)!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let values = postString


    request.HTTPBody = values.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    var dictionaryVal:NSDictionary!

    var semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
    { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        var responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        do{
            print(">>>",responseString!)
            var dataExample : NSData = (responseString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))!
            dictionaryVal = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataExample, options:.MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
        }
        catch
        {
            responseString = nil
            print("Error")
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }
    task.resume()
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    return dictionaryVal!

}
```

Comment: I find it strange that you have implemented the response handler for the NSURLSession, but dont understand how to know when you have received the response... the handler executes when you have the response...

Comment: I took the code from net.. I didn't understood the logic though

Comment: ah well, in that case, everything inside the curly brackets attached to `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)` is being executed when the webservices comes back with a response, so in there you would put the text in your textfield and stop loading indicators etc

Comment: <edit> actually nevermind, the semaphore will halt it, but that is bad practise cause it may cause your app to freeze until the response comes back form the server, unless this whole method is executed on a background thread

Comment: Can u explain how to do this whole method in background thread.. I tried it after your suggestion but couldn't figure out right method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UIActivityIndicatorView` to display Process Indicator as used in following function. You can also disable UserInteraction on start and enable after response.

```
func APICall()
{
    var sessionConfiguration:NSURLSessionConfiguration!
    var session:NSURLSession!

    // *** create IBOutlet of it and connect with indicator ***
    let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    // *** Hide indicator when stop animating ***
    indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

    sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60
    sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 120
    sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

    session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

    let requestURLString = "http://Your API URL"
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: requestURLString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!)!)

    // *** start indicator before sending request ***
    indicator.startAnimating()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in

        // *** hide indicator on response on Main Thread ***
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            indicator.stopAnimating()
        })

        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            switch httpResponse.statusCode
            {
            case 200:

                print("Successful response.")

            default:
                print("Error :\(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: i will try it out.. much appreciated bro

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for it you have to use `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` and it's methods:

[image: this is the screen of system code]